# C++ template: overload operator +, while the return type determined by input type

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

Suppose that I have following class

```
template<unsigned char B, unsigned char F>
class Foo
{
   .....
}
```

I hope to overload the operator+ so that if the two inputs are of

```
Foo<B1, F1>
```

and

```
Foo<B2, F2>,
```

respectively, I would like the return value is type of

```
Foo<max(B1, B2), max(F1, F2)>.
```

or something like

```
Foo<max(B1-F1, B2-F2)+max(F1, F2), max(F1, F2)>.
```

Any tips?

Comment: Pretty straight forward.... T T::operator +(const T& b) const; - See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4421706/1155650

Comment: my poster didn't show correctly

Comment: please be more precise when you post question are you trying to find the maximum of two objects, or sum of two objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just compute your new type in the operator+ return type, and use MPL for comparisons
Moreover, you don't need friend for that neither your operator+ need to be mutable.

Simple example with simple classes:

```
#include <boost/mpl/max.hpp>

template<unsigned char B, unsigned char F>
class Foo
{};

template< unsigned char B1, unsigned char F1
        , unsigned char B2, unsigned char F2
        >
Foo< boost::mpl::max_<boost::mpl_::char_<B1>, boost::mpl_::char_<B2> >::value
   , boost::mpl::max_<boost::mpl_::char_<F1>, boost::mpl_::char_<F2> >::value
   >
operator+(Foo<B1,F1> const& a, Foo<B2,F2> const& b)
{
  Foo< boost::mpl::max_<boost::mpl_::char_<B1>, boost::mpl_::char_<B2> >::value
   , boost::mpl::max_<boost::mpl_::char_<F1>, boost::mpl_::char_<F2> >::value
   > that;
  return that;
}
```

Now, notice how it is cumbersome. An usual idiom in this case is to ue Boost MPL Integral Types instead of raw value whenever possible

```
#include <boost/mpl/max.hpp>

template<class B, class F>
class Foo
{};

template< class B1, class F1
        , class B2, class F2
        >
Foo< typename boost::mpl::max_<B1, B2>::type
   , typename boost::mpl::max_<F1, F2>::type
   >
operator+(Foo<B1,F1> const& a, Foo<B2,F2> const& b)
{
   Foo< typename boost::mpl::max_<B1, B2>::type
      , typename boost::mpl::max_<F1, F2>::type
      > that;
  return that;
}

Foo< boost::mpl::int_<4>, boost::mpl::int_<8> > x;
```

EDIT:
Also, this makes the return type of + a bit complex to write down in pre_C++11 auto.
Another classical stuff is to make this into a function object following the result_of protocol so you have a meta-function handy to compute the return type in an opaque way.

Comment: Do you know how to achieve the same thing by C++11?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for something like this.

```
foo a,b,c;
a = b + c;
```

For that you will need to overload the '=' operator  as well.

```
enter code here
    template <typename t,typename f>
    foo& operator + (const foo& source)
    {
        //add the date members
        return *this;
    }
```

and then overload the = operator and you should be able to achieve your desired operation.

Comment: I don't think you have to overload =operator. a class object is assigned to a class object of same type. the default operator = should work okay

Comment: @Rohit:c++ compiler does provide a = operator but it does shallow copying just like the default copy constructor so it is recommended and a good practice to overload the operator

Comment: Wont shallow copy be enough as there isnt any pointers involved?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible, perhaps using boost MPL[1].

[1] http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/mpl/doc/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template <unsigned char A, unsigned char B>
struct max {
  enum { value = A>B ? A : B};
};

template <unsigned char B, unsigned char F>
class Foo {};

template <unsigned char B, unsigned char F>
std::ostream&
operator<<(std::ostream& os, Foo<B, F>) {
  return os << "Foo<" << (int)B << "," << (int)F << ">";
}

template <unsigned char B1, unsigned char F1,
          unsigned char B2, unsigned char F2>
Foo<max<B1, B2>::value, max<F1, F2>::value>
operator+( const Foo<B1, F1>&, const Foo<B2, F2>& )
{
  return Foo<max<B1, B2>::value, max<F1, F2>::value>();
}

int main() {
  Foo<1,3> foo13;
  Foo<0,4> foo04;

  std::cout << foo13 << "\n";
  std::cout << foo04 << "\n";
  std::cout << foo13 + foo04 << "\n";
}
```